# Unity - Unable to Join strings from a list together

Tags: c#, list, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a bingo caller so I have a list of numbers 1-90 and it randomly picks one, moves it from the 'TobeCalled' List and into 'DeadNumbers' List, this all works fine. The problem I have is that I want to print the list as an object on the screen, so convert it to a string and print it using text apart form I get the error.

**Assets\Random_Number.cs(41,17): error CS0103: The name 'String' does not exist in the current context**

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Random_Number : MonoBehaviour
{

  public List <int> ListofNumbers = new List<int>(); // List of the numbers being called
  public List <string> DeadNumbers = new List<string>(); // List of numbers that have been called

  public Text text_to_be_Printed; // Text Element

  private int numberSelected;
  private string numberSelected_str;
  public string DeadNumbers_str;

  void Start() {
    text_to_be_Printed = GetComponent<Text>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 90; i++){

        ListofNumbers.Add(i); // Makes a list of all the numbers 

      }

  }

  void Update()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){ // If space is pressed -text
      numberSelected = ListofNumbers[Random.Range (0, ListofNumbers.Count)]; // Get a random number text

      numberSelected_str = numberSelected.ToString();
      text_to_be_Printed.text = numberSelected_str;

      DeadNumbers.Add(numberSelected_str);
      ListofNumbers.Remove(numberSelected);

      Debug.Log(String.Join(", ", DeadNumbers));

      // DeadNumbers_str = String.Join(",", DeadNumbers);
      // Debug.Log(DeadNumbers_str);
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried uning String.Join but i get the error above, I'm pertty new to Unity and c# so any help would be appricated

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] as theres a lot of code and its not clear which line  you actually have a problem on.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `using System;` at the top of your file. `String` class is located at `System` namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Random_Number : MonoBehaviour
{

  public List <int> ListofNumbers = new List<int>(); // List of the numbers being called
  public List <string> DeadNumbers = new List<string>(); // List of numbers that have been called

  public Text text_to_be_Printed; // Text Element

  private int numberSelected;
  private string numberSelected_str;
  public string DeadNumbers_str;

  void Start() {
    text_to_be_Printed = GetComponent<Text>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 90; i++){

        ListofNumbers.Add(i); // Makes a list of all the numbers 

      }

  }

  void Update()
  {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){ // If space is pressed -text
      numberSelected = ListofNumbers[Random.Range (0, ListofNumbers.Count)]; // Get a random number text

      numberSelected_str = numberSelected.ToString();
      text_to_be_Printed.text = numberSelected_str;

      DeadNumbers.Add(numberSelected_str);
      ListofNumbers.Remove(numberSelected);

      Debug.Log(String.Join(", ", DeadNumbers));

      // DeadNumbers_str = String.Join(",", DeadNumbers);
      // Debug.Log(DeadNumbers_str);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [foobar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622775/7111561)

`string` (small `s`) as type keyword is the same as `System.String` so you could also simply use `string.Join` instead then you don't need the `using System;`